# Cannot get TCP port information from Kubernetes host-Openshift Origin-oc

Tags: openshift-origin

I was following Openshift's [Local Cluster Management](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#linux) documentation.
After I ran `oc cluster up`

```
[root@user ~]# oc cluster up
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.6.0 ...
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... 
   WARNING: Docker version is 1.21, it needs to be >= 1.22
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.6.0 image ... OK
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... OK
-- Checking for available ports ... FAIL
   Error: Cannot get TCP port information from Kubernetes host
   Caused By:
     Error: cannot create container using image openshift/origin:v3.6.0
     Caused By:
       Error: Error response from daemon: SHM size must be greater then 0
[root@ip-172-31-0-186 ~]# oc cluster up --loglevel=5
-- Checking OpenShift client ... 
-- Checking Docker client ... 
I0803 04:30:33.543172    1417 up.go:590] No Docker environment variables found. Will attempt default socket.
I0803 04:30:33.543221    1417 up.go:595] No Docker host (DOCKER_HOST) configured. Will attempt default socket.
-- Checking Docker version ... 
I0803 04:30:33.543240    1417 helper.go:114] Retrieving Docker version
I0803 04:30:33.554087    1417 helper.go:120] Docker version results: &types.Version{Version:"1.9.1", APIVersion:"1.21", GitCommit:"78ee77d/1.9.1", GoVersion:"go1.4.2", Os:"linux", Arch:"amd64", KernelVersion:"3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64", Experimental:false, BuildTime:""}
I0803 04:30:33.554126    1417 helper.go:124] APIVersion: 1.21
I0803 04:30:33.554158    1417 up.go:686] Checking that docker API version is at least 1.22

   WARNING: Docker version is 1.21, it needs to be >= 1.22
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... 
I0803 04:30:33.554181    1417 helper.go:171] Inspecting docker container "origin"
I0803 04:30:33.555084    1417 helper.go:175] Container "origin" was not found
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.6.0 image ... 
I0803 04:30:33.555101    1417 helper.go:143] Inspecting Docker image "openshift/origin:v3.6.0"
I0803 04:30:33.556444    1417 helper.go:146] Image "openshift/origin:v3.6.0" found: &types.ImageInspect{ID:"c6d16974c8a3a5da3ab799533daa2dbd54e56b1f0ebbad59345154fc8e836ff2", RepoTags:[]string{"docker.io/openshift/origin:v3.6.0"}, RepoDigests:[]string{}, Parent:"395d30169bc02cca2e7083926b0fd6f2e6b7034a6de41a811cce0ab7c7473fca", Comment:"", Created:"2017-08-01T18:34:13.736398725Z", Container:"ae53137cc1b98b2f93051589d6aee252e505ac82f8e7a31f5ab49bfc0e9dc91a", ContainerConfig:(*container.Config)(0xc420277b00), DockerVersion:"1.12.6", Author:"", Config:(*container.Config)(0xc4202e2120), Architecture:"amd64", Os:"linux", Size:611206034, VirtualSize:974248741, GraphDriver:types.GraphDriverData{Name:"devicemapper", Data:map[string]string{"DeviceId":"7", "DeviceName":"docker-202:2-25214823-c6d16974c8a3a5da3ab799533daa2dbd54e56b1f0ebbad59345154fc8e836ff2", "DeviceSize":"107374182400"}}, RootFS:types.RootFS{Type:"", Layers:[]string(nil), BaseLayer:""}}
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... 
I0803 04:30:33.556503    1417 helper.go:65] Retrieving Docker daemon info
I0803 04:30:33.681753    1417 helper.go:71] Docker daemon info: &types.Info{ID:"IITV:S6LY:XNQS:LA63:VAH6:POZR:RGCW:MFWK:OTI7:DEII:AQK5:FDC6", Containers:0, ContainersRunning:0, ContainersPaused:0, ContainersStopped:0, Images:6, Driver:"devicemapper", DriverStatus:[][2]string{[2]string{"Pool Name", "docker-202:2-25214823-pool"}, [2]string{"Pool Blocksize", "65.54 kB"}, [2]string{"Base Device Size", "107.4 GB"}, [2]string{"Backing Filesystem", ""}, [2]string{"Data file", "/dev/loop0"}, [2]string{"Metadata file", "/dev/loop1"}, [2]string{"Data Space Used", "1.091 GB"}, [2]string{"Data Space Total", "107.4 GB"}, [2]string{"Data Space Available", "18.09 GB"}, [2]string{"Metadata Space Used", "1.339 MB"}, [2]string{"Metadata Space Total", "2.147 GB"}, [2]string{"Metadata Space Available", "2.146 GB"}, [2]string{"Udev Sync Supported", "true"}, [2]string{"Deferred Removal Enabled", "false"}, [2]string{"Deferred Deletion Enabled", "false"}, [2]string{"Deferred Deleted Device Count", "0"}, [2]string{"Data loop file", "/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data"}, [2]string{"Metadata loop file", "/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata"}, [2]string{"Library Version", "1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)"}}, SystemStatus:[][2]string(nil), Plugins:types.PluginsInfo{Volume:[]string(nil), Network:[]string(nil), Authorization:[]string(nil)}, MemoryLimit:true, SwapLimit:true, KernelMemory:false, CPUCfsPeriod:true, CPUCfsQuota:true, CPUShares:false, CPUSet:false, IPv4Forwarding:true, BridgeNfIptables:true, BridgeNfIP6tables:true, Debug:false, NFd:15, OomKillDisable:true, NGoroutines:25, SystemTime:"2017-08-03T04:30:33.681150233-04:00", ExecutionDriver:"native-0.2", LoggingDriver:"json-file", CgroupDriver:"", NEventsListener:0, KernelVersion:"3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64", OperatingSystem:"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)", OSType:"", Architecture:"", IndexServerAddress:"https://index.docker.io/v1/", RegistryConfig:(*registry.ServiceConfig)(0xc4210fb700), NCPU:2, MemTotal:3973541888, DockerRootDir:"/var/lib/docker", HTTPProxy:"", HTTPSProxy:"", NoProxy:"", Name:"ip-172-31-0-186.us-west-2.compute.internal", Labels:[]string(nil), ExperimentalBuild:false, ServerVersion:"1.9.1", ClusterStore:"", ClusterAdvertise:"", SecurityOptions:[]string(nil)}
I0803 04:30:33.681847    1417 helper.go:42] Looking for "172.30.0.0/16" in []*registry.NetIPNet{(*registry.NetIPNet)(0xc4210f1a10), (*registry.NetIPNet)(0xc4210f1a70)}
I0803 04:30:33.681859    1417 helper.go:46] Found "172.30.0.0/16"
-- Checking for available ports ... 
I0803 04:30:33.681920    1417 run.go:181] Creating container named ""
config:
  image: openshift/origin:v3.6.0
  entry point:
    /bin/bash
  command:
    -c
    cat /proc/net/tcp && ( [ -e /proc/net/tcp6 ] && cat /proc/net/tcp6 || true)

host config:
  pid mode: host
  user mode: 
  network mode: host

FAIL
   Error: Cannot get TCP port information from Kubernetes host
   Caused By:
     Error: cannot create container using image openshift/origin:v3.6.0
     Caused By:
       Error: Error response from daemon: SHM size must be greater then 0
```

I have placed kubernetes config file in `.kube/config`. Still getting same error. Kubernetes cluster should be in same machine?

## UPDATE-1

1. Install latest version from [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/#prerequisites)
2. To resolve dependency, installed container-selinux (sudo yum install ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm)
3. After I try to bringup the cluster with `oc cluster up`. This time, it failing at docker configuration.

   [root@ip-172-31-0-186 ~]# oc cluster up
   Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.6.0 ...
   -- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
   -- Checking Docker client ... OK
   -- Checking Docker version ... OK
   -- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
   -- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.6.0 image ... OK
   -- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... FAIL
   Error: did not detect an --insecure-registry argument on the Docker daemon
   Solution:

   Ensure that the Docker daemon is running with the following argument:
       --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16

Docs says, update the `--insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16` in `/etc/sysconf/docker`. But for new version of docker there is no file in that location. Any way I have created and updated the `/etc/sysconf/docker`. But still getting the above error.

Comment: The docker version may be an issue.  What specific version of Docker are you running?

Comment: @Clayton I have update docker (`Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`) now. Getting insecure registry error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is insecure registry configuration. Specify insecure registry in `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker` with below config

```
{
   "insecure-registries": [
     "172.30.0.0/16"
   ]
}
```

This is working latest docker also.

Answer (score 0):

For any particular version of Kubernetes or OpenShift the supported Docker version is little behind.

So I would advise you to install docker not the latest one from docker documentation. But install using your linux distribution's package manager. For Fedora and CentOS just do:

```
sudo yum install -y docker
```

Once you have done that all the dependency management will be taken care of and you don't need to manually install anything else.

Now that you have installed docker using the package manager you will find the `/etc/sysconfig/docker`. And you can add that line `--insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16`.

HTH.